# Jest + angular +unit test

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am very new to Angular testing with JEST. So the following is the code what i have tried so far...

**spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
//All import stuff here
describe('test1', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        const ngbActiveModalStub = { close: () => ({}) };
        //All my service stub goes here
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({      
          providers: [        
            mycomponent,
            { provide: NgbActiveModal, useValue: ngbActiveModalStub }]
        });
       component = TestBed.get(mycomponent)
    });
   it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The above test executed successfully. Now i want to write test case for standalone function by setting the value. Consider i have a function in ts file as follows:

**component.ts**

```
updateValueInDropDown($event, i) {   
    
    if($event.target.value == 'abct') {      
      this.active= true;         
    } else {
      this.active= false;      
    }    
  }

abc() {    
if(this.active== true) {
   const value= this.form.value.xyz;
    this.service.validate(value).subscribe(
      (res)=>{
       },
      (error) => {
      });
  }
}
```

SO how ca make the `active` as true in testcase so that the following API will be invoked and test this function in my unit test case file. Please share your ideas.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided us with a bit more detail about the component. How does it become "active" in the real app (how and when is the variable set true in production code) ?

Comment: @ Apokralipsa "active" will be set true if user selects a particular value in dropdown. Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

You can set values to component variables ('this' variables) by using 'component.variableName'.

```js
it('test abc method', () => {
  // Set this.active to true
  component.active = true;

  // Rest of the testing.... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would try to do in this case is to simulate the behaviour of the user. If the user needs to select something on a dropdown to make the validation run, then I think you should also do it in tests. This way you both document the behaviour of the component, and test the users path.

An example could be:

```
describe('when the user selects "abct" on the dropdown', () => { // this description could be improved.

    beforeEach(() => {
        selectValue('abct');
        ...
    })

    it('should validate the provided value', () => {
        // see below
    })
})

function selectValue(value: string) {
    // Depending on the implementation of your dropdown (simple select element, a component from Angular Material or sth else) this may be different.
    // Maybe simply publishing the change event would suffice? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947788/2842142
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.dropdown'))
        .nativeElement
        .click();
    
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
    fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('option'))
        .map(option => option.nativeElement)
        .find(option => option.innerText === value) // or option.value === value
        .click();
}
```

As to how exactly test if the validation occurs - you may have different options.
In most cases I would check the results of validation. You could query for some changes in the dom or some validation messages.

There might be cases where it would make sense to provide a mock service, spy on calls (`spyOn(service, 'validate')`) and check if the method was called during the test (`expect(service.validate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedValue)`). I would consider it mostly if the service is being used in more places and has its own tests written.